# How to create a Tkinter taskbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, taskbar, replit

I am using [repl.it(link to my project)](https://repl.it/@CodingAndMemes/WinSim) and I am wanting to create a taskbar so that when the user clicks on it the app will be called. To call the functions I am using:

```py
button = tk.Button(window, 
                   text="Text",
                   command=command
)
```

Comment: Show us a minimal example.

Comment: ***I am using repl.it***: You can't use Tkinter on reply.it!

Comment: @stovfl Actually, you can!

Comment: The built-in `PhotoImage()` does not support `jpeg`, use `Pillow.ImageTk.PhotoImage()` instead.

Comment: PhotoImage() only allows gif, ppm, and some other formats.

Comment: @TheMaker: I get **_TclError: no display ...**, does it only work having a account?

Comment: you have to add mainloop() at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a taskbar, you can just make a canvas!

Here is some code I used:

```py
taskwidth = Desktop.winfo_screenwidth()
taskheight = Desktop.winfo_screenheight()
Port = Canvas(Desktop, height = 0.1 * (taskheight), width = taskwidth, bg = "skyblue", highlightthickness = 0)
Port.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.995, anchor = "center")
```

This would scale to any screen, and it would go to the bottom.

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://repl.it/@CodingAndMemes/Taskbar-Test

It doesn’t appear to be working @TheMaker

Comment: you are using a pygame repl. switch to tkinter

Comment: Here, I made the repl for you: https://repl.it/@stream/taskbar

Comment: Could you upvote this! I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, @TheMaker!